# How can I use a non-const type on my ARC code?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Following one of [Apple's examples](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/getObjects:range:) I'm getting an

```
Pointer to non-const type 'id' with no explicit ownership
```

And a few other errors...
This is my snippet:

```
NSArray *mArray = argsList;
id *objects;
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(2, [argsList count]);
objects = malloc(sizeof(NSString *) * range.length);
[mArray getObjects:objects range:range];
for (i = 0; i < range.length; i++) {
    NSLog(@"Args: %@", objects[i]);
}
free(objects);
```

And the error starts in the second line. My guess is that I would have to disable ARC, but if there is a way to keep it I would be happier.
How can I go about this? (YES! I need an id*)

Comment: You need `__unsafe_unretained id  * objects;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Cy-4AH suggested `__unsafe_unretained` solved the problem:

Now it looks like:

```
NSArray *mArray = argsList;
__unsafe_unretained id *objects;
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(1, [argsList count]-1);
objects = (__unsafe_unretained id*)malloc(sizeof(NSString *) * range.length);
[mArray getObjects:objects range:range];
```